# how to update variable value from imacros code

Tags: javascript, imacros

I need to update length variable that was defined  in imacros js in `macro.js`. I have tried different code but not able to pass information from imacros(js on page) to imacro.js (js of imacro);

for example;

```
var lenght = 0;

iimPlay("CODE:URL GOTO=JAVASCRIPT:var<SP>len=window.document.getElementById('table1').getElementsByTag('tr');");
```

now how to pass that inner len variable info to outer length variable. i need to run a loop based on length.

I can pass info from JS part to Imacros part with iimSet('var',var); is there any way I can update JS variable's value inside imacros code.;

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick with an ‘alert’ dialog:

```
var length = 0;
iimPlay("CODE:URL GOTO=JAVASCRIPT:alert(window.document.getElementById('table1').getElementsByTag('tr').length);");
length = parseInt(iimGetErrorText().match(/Dialog message: "(.*)",/)[1]);
```